# Error in fetching Last ID column value after an insert statement in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to fetch the last `ID` number after an `INSERT` event in AWS Redshift. For this, I have written a Stored Procedure in AWS Redshift as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myschema.uspgtest(paramname varchar(10),runID int, INOUT 
activitylogid integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  v_WorkflowID BIGINT;
  Status VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
  cnt INT;  
BEGIN
  ----Internal SQL Codes----
  ----The below code is part of main code-----
  IF (WorkflowID IS NULL OR Status = 'Completed' OR cnt = 0) THEN
  INSERT INTO myschema."Table_1" ("Status", "CreatedDatetime", 
  "UpdatedDatetime", "Type")
  VALUES ('In-Progress', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, paramname) 
  RETURNING ID INTO v_WorkflowID; 
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO myschema."Table_2" ("ParentActivityLogID", "CreatedDateTime", 
  "UpdatedDateTime", "WorkflowID","RunID")
  VALUES (0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, v_WorkflowID,runID) RETURNING 
  ActivityLogID INTO activitylogid;   
END;
$$
```

The above SP is throwing an error as below:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function 
"uspgtest" near line 18 [ErrorId: <errorId>]
```

Not able to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: `RETURNING` isn't part of the Redshift SQL dialect. And before you respond with "Redshift is based on Postgres!" it's nominally based on 8.0, and `RETURNING` was added in (as far as I can tell) 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have worked around this issue.

As kdgregory mentioned that `RETURNING` is not supported in Redshift, I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITIONED BY..` approach. Therefore, we can re-write the SP as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myschema.uspgtest(p_paramname IN varchar(10),p_runID IN int, INOUT P_activitylogid integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  v_WorkflowID BIGINT;
  Status VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
  cnt INT;  
BEGIN
  ----Internal SQL Codes----
  ----The below code is part of main code-----
  IF (WorkflowID IS NULL OR Status = 'Completed' OR cnt = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO myschema."Table_1" ("Status", "CreatedDatetime", 
   "UpdatedDatetime", "Type")
    VALUES ('In-Progress', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, paramname) 
  ----RETURNING ID INTO v_WorkflowID; ---Discarding this part
  END IF;
  ----This part is added----
  SELECT A."workflowid" INTO v_workflowid FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT "workflowid",ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
  "status","paramname" ORDER BY "createddatetime" DESC)rnk FROM 
  myschema."Table_1" WHERE "paramname"=p_paramname)A WHERE A.rnk=1;

  INSERT INTO myschema."Table_2" ("ParentActivityLogID", "CreatedDateTime", 
  "UpdatedDateTime", "WorkflowID","RunID")
  VALUES (0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, v_WorkflowID,p_runID)
  
  SELECT B."activitylogid" INTO p_activitylogid FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT "activitylogid", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
  "paramname" ORDER BY "CreatedDateTime" DESC)rnk FROM myschema."Table_2" 
  WHERE "paramname"=p_paramname)B WHERE B.rnk=1;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  RAISE INFO 'error'
END;
$$
```

Hope this helps others.